# NSSet how to extract object randomly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsset

I am not sure about how NSSet's `anyObject` work. What does it mean that "The object returned is chosen at the set’s convenience" (from the [NSSet class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSSet)) ?

Further, how can I best extract objects randomly from a NSSet? I was thinking about getting `allObjects` in an array and then `myArray[arc4random_uniform(x)]` where x is the number of objects in the array.

Comment: Are you ok with repeats?

Comment: Rather curious about that myself, I guess you could call anyObject a random number of times but your array solution sounds better.

Comment: I guess converting NSArray to NSSet back and forth won't be a good way to shuffle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually, `NSSet` instances are created with a `CFHash` backing, so they almost always return the first object in that hash, as it is the fastest to look up. The reason it says

> The object returned is chosen at the set’s convenience—the selection is not guaranteed to be random.

Is because you don't always know it will have a backing array. For all you know, the `NSSet` instance you have has a `NSDictionary` backing it, or some other similar data structure.

So, in conclusion, if you need a random object from a `NSSet`, don't use `-anyObject`, instead  use `allObjects:` and then shuffle that array.

Comment: Yes! I think this puts me at the rep cap for today!

Comment: Actually, `NSSet` is created with a `CFBasicHash` backing. Making assumptions based on the idea that the set is array-backed is just as unsafe as making assumptions based on the idea that it is randomly sorted.

Comment: See [`CFSet.c`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFSet.c) for the implementation of `NSSet` (whose concrete subclasses are equivalent to `CFSet` instances.)

Answer (score 14):

Quote from [NSSet Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The object returned is chosen at the set’s convenience—the selection is not guaranteed to be random.

For "randomness", convert the `NSSet` to an `NSArray` using `[theSet allObjects]`.
Next, pick any object randomly using `arc4random_uniform()`.

Comment: Lets be fair here, you will also need to initialize the randomizer differently each startup for it truly to be random, and even then, it is pseudorandom :-)  +1

Answer (score 4):

The documentation reads that `anyObject` returns

> One of the objects in the set, or nil if the set contains no objects.
>   The object returned is chosen at the set’s convenience—the selection
>   is not guaranteed to be random.

Most likely there is some deterministic algorithm at work.

The most reliable thing to do would be, as you suggest, to create an `NSArray` using the `NSSet` method `allObjects`, and then choose a random element from that with `arc4random() % N` where `N` is the `count` of the `NSArray`.

Comment: Better to use arc4random_uniform instead just using the modulo operator, as fabio suggested in his question, to avoid modulo bias.

Answer (score 1):

I use arc4random() and two mutable arrays to get a random and unique set of objects:

```
NSMutableArray *selectionPool = ...;

int numberOfObjectsToSelect = x;

NSMutableArray *selectedObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfObjectsToSelect];

int modulus = selectionPool.count - 1;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjectsToSelect; i++) {

    int j = arc4random() % (modulus--);
    [selectedObjects addObject:[selectionPool objectAtIndex:j]];
    [selectionPool removeObjectAtIndex:j];

}
```

I'm not sure how efficient it would be for large collections, but it's worked for me with collections that number in the low 100s of objects.

Comment: would get division by zero exception if `numberOfObjectsToSelect == selectionPool.count`